# Migrate DNS from current host for multiple records

Tags: dns, cloudflare

What is the best way to quickly update multiple client domain DNS and keep switchover downtime to a minimum?

I am currently using vanity nameservers and glue record on my Primary domain, at the domain registrar like so;

1) mycompany.com which has nameservers of ns1.powerdns.com & ns2.powerdns.com (from Host) and I have glue records of my vanity nameservers; ns1.mycompany.com (IP 1.2.3.4) & ns1.mycompany.com (IP 5.6.7.8). 
2) in Host providers DNS managment, I have set up NS records to point to the ns1.powerdns.com & ns2.powerdns.com and I also have A records in there. 
3) Client domains set up in server with zone records.

This allows me to point my client domains to the vanity nameservers e.g. 
myclient1.com > ns1.mycompany.com and ns2.mycompany.com, 
myclient2.com > ns1.mycompany.com and ns2.mycompany.com
and so on

But I need to move DNS away from hosting provider as it has been unreliable.  I don't want the additional complexity of managing my own DNS server.

So my question is this:

If I move to e.g. Cloudflare or DNSME (the latter seem to have free vanity nameservers support) - what would the best set up be?

A) Would I simply set up one "master" DNS record for mycompany.com that points to my server IP / nameservers - and that would result in the client domains automatically following / re-routing / bouncing their DNS lookup through the DNSME "master" record?  What is the likely client domain interruption with this method?

B) Or should I update all client domain registrar records to point to the DNSME NS individually and then set up separate records (or a template) for each client domain to point to my server?

I assume only B above would mean any client domain nameserver changes would benefit from CDN type propagation?

Comment: Moving away from your own DNS servers is a very good idea.   Professional DNS hosting is both cheap and reliable.

Comment: Yes, but what is the most efficient method ?